# Is it safe to cast jlong to long?

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I'm developing a native plugin for Android with JNI in C++. I want to print out a `jlong` value, which is [defined as a 64-bit value](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/types.html). Is it safe to cast it directly to a long, or are there any platform-specific issues I should be aware of?

```
jlong foo = 2;

// This results in the following warning:
// Format specifier '%ld' requires 'long' argument instead of 'jlong'.
printf("%ld", foo);

// This works without a warning.
printf("%ld", (long)foo);
```

Comment: In C and C++ `long` is required to be at least 32 bits. `long long` is required to be at least 64 bits.

Comment: In VC++ of VS2013, platform x64: sizeof (long): 4. I would prefer `long long` if 64 bit is required for `jlong`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## No. Yes.

Java, as you have correctly noticed, defines `long` as a 64 bit number. C++ does not do that `long` is only guaranteed to be at least as large as `int`, so it might as well be a 32-bit number.

However, *it so happens* that given the combination "Android" + "64 bit", indeed `long` is a 64-bit integer. That's much different from e.g. Windows where it's still just a 32-bit integer.
So, assuming you are writing for 64-bit only, you *could* stop reading here and now.

## But, why the trouble?

C++ borrows the `<cstdint>` header from C, which defines among others the type `int64_t`. So you need to use something of which you know is a 64-bit type and you're worried it might not fit?

Well, use a type that is *guaranteed* to cope with that:

```
#include <cstdio>
using my_jlong = int64_t;
```

Comment: In C and C++, `long` must, indeed, be at least as large as `int`. But it must also be at least 32 bits. `int` can be 16 bits.

Comment: `int64_t` is actually an *optional* type.  Per **7.20.1.1 Exact-width integer types**, paragraph 3 of [the C Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf): *These types are optional. ...* So, using `int64_t` is not technically *guaranteed* to work, although it practically is.  `int_least64_t` and `int_fast64_t` are the *required* types.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: That's right, although I yet have to see a compiler that doesn't support it. For those concerned that it might be a problem, there's still `int_least64_t` which is not optional. Like all the `least` versions, it might be larger than 64 bits but that would be harmless (it will most probably be exactly 64 bits, anyway). I prefer the "no least" versions since it's "mostly harmless" and fewer characters to type.

Comment: [Android 12 is the first version of the OS to support 64-bit only builds.](https://blog.esper.io/android-dessert-bites-3-road-to-64-bit-3123759/#:~:text=Android%2012%20is%20the%20first%20version%20of%20the%20OS%20to%20support%2064%2Dbit%20only%20builds.)

Answer (score 1):

The minimum range of values the C++ standard requires a `long` to represent (`-2147483647` to `2147483647`), which means it could be a 32-bit type.   Converting a `jlong` value to `long` that exceeds the range of a 32-bit type - if that is what a `long` is for your target implementation - will yield undefined behaviour.

The minimum required range (`-9223372036854775807` to `9223372036854775807`) of values that a `long long` can represent means it is a 64-bit type (or better).

The potential problem results from edge-cases: specifically the extreme (largest representable negative or largest positive values in the types), since 64-bit integral types can represent an even number of values, one of which is zero.  This means the number of positive values a 64-bit type can represent is one different (either more or less) than the number of negative values it can represent.  If `jlong` represents a different range of values than a `long long`  (e.g. `jlong` represents the range `-9223372036854775807` to `9223372036854775808`, while `long long` represents `-9223372036854775808` to `9223372036854775807`)  then the result of converting such extreme values can give undefined behaviour.

In short, there no guarantee that a `long long` will be able to represent exactly the same range of values as a `jlong`.  Practically, you will find most modern target platforms will be alright.  However, this was not true of some older systems and (theoretically at least) could change again in future.

If you can guarantee (e.g. through analysis of your Java code) that your `jlong` never holds one of the offending extreme values that a `long long` may not be able to represent, then there will be no problem converting to a `long long`.  There will also be no problem if you can guarantee (e.g. by referring to documentation for each target system and C++ compiler) that a `long long` supports at least the same range of values as a `jlong`.

You probably would be better off printing using C++ streams (which have insertion operators overloaded for each standard type) than using C I/O (which relies on you getting the format string right).