# Convert long to jlong in C (Native Android)

Tags: android, c, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I am developing an Android app for which I am using some decompression libraries.

**Code:**

```
size_t test = lzfse_decode_buffer(dst_buffer, dst_size, src_buffer, src_size, NULL);

    ALOG("Size of test %d.",test); // output is 319488
    ALOG("Size of test after casting  %ld.",(jlong)test); // output is -125648933
```

I want to convert the test variable from **size_t** to **jlong**. Casting the variable is causing error in value.

Comment: Look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44996205/is-it-safe-to-cast-jlong-to-long#44996798

Comment: *Casting the variable is causing error in value.* Are you sure that's where your problem is?  `%d` is the wrong `printf()` format specifier for a `size_t`, and as noted in the linked question, `jlong` is a 64-bit data type, while `%ld` might not refer to a 64-bit type.